# relative import error while importing file from diffrent package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I created the following directory structure.

```
package1/
   __init__.py
   file1.py
   file2.py
package2/
   __init__.py
   utils.py
```

I have to import utils.py from package2 at file2.py in package1.
I tried using

```
from .package2 import utils
```

but got error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.package2'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `file2` you can add the root directory of `package1` and `package2` to your path:

```
import os, sys
this_dir, _ = os.path.split(__file__)
root_dir = os.path.dirname(this_dir)
sys.path.append(root_dir)
```

Then import:

```
from package2 import utils
```

Comment: The first part shouldn't be necessary. The issue is the "." he put in `from .package2 import utils`

Comment: I tested and I don't believe this is true. Packages 1 and 2 are in the same directory, so the import in file2 would have to know to traverse up 2 directories then back down 1 to package2